# Is the size of a text file containing a string the exact same as 2 text files each containing half of the original string?

Tags: c++, textfiles

If I have a string 'abcde', and I saved it in file1.txt, and saved 'abc' in file2.txt, and 'de' in file3.txt, does the sum of the sizes of file2.txt and file3.txt is *exactly* equal to file1.txt?

I tried it and they seem to be equal, but maybe the difference is so small it doesn't appear on just 2 files, but splitting the info into a thousand file would make a difference.

I ask this because I'm making a program for university, and my algorithm creates a lot of text files with info in them. My professor told me to put all the info in 1 file to save space, but having multiple files is more organized and easier for coding.

Testing on Linux Mint, and language used is c++ if that makes a difference.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is only the *data size* and not the size *on the disk*.

Data is allocated on the disk in units that depend on how the disk was formatted.
Most common sizes are 4K (4096) or 512.
The space after the data and up to the end of the last allocation unit is
simply wasted.

So your professor is right: Concentrating the data in one file will reduce
wasted space, unless the data of the file is exactly a multiple
of the allocation unit (which only happens very rarely unless planned for).